# JDBC ODBC bridge for Mac OSX

Tags: macos, jdbc-odbc

I am having a hard time establishing a connection to my database file using JDBC-ODBC bridge. The driver I am using is sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver but I believe it is not present on Mac OSX by default and hence throws an exception for class not found.

I googled for the driver but could not find much useful information. Can somebody please help me establish the connection? Or send me any link which contains information I am looking for?

Thanks,

Comment: If i recall you need a database specific driver.. fore example `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Sun's and Oracle's [official positions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) have long been that --

> the [JVM-bundled] JDBC-ODBC Bridge should be considered a transitional solution [...] Oracle does not support the JDBC-ODBC Bridge.

However, my employer, [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), has produced enterprise-grade commercial Type 1 Bridges between JDBC and ODBC since JVM 1.0.  Current versions are fully compatible with Java 6, 7, and 8, and with OS X, from Lion to Yosemite (10.7 - 10.10).  You can learn more here --

- [Single-Tier JDBC-ODBC Bridge Driver](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-st/) -- a JDBC driver for ODBC data sources
- [Single-Tier ODBC-JDBC Bridge Driver](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-jdbc-st/) -- an ODBC driver for JDBC data sources